# Filter aggregation and sorting

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents with 2 fields, application_id and location_id.
The combination of those 2 fields maps back to services, as follow (for example):

```
application_id  location_id     service_id
             1            1              1
             2            1              2
             1            2              3
             2            2              3
```

I have **a lot** of those services and for several reasons, the service_id cannot/won't be computed prior to indexing my documents.

Hence, **service_id field does not exist**, and I can't/won't change that.

I would like to filter the service_id and get the top 5 ones that have the largest amount of documents.

I can easily create filters for my service_ids:

```
"aggs": {
  "services": {
    "filters": {
      "filters": {
        "service 1": {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "application_id:1 AND location_id:1"
          }
        },
        "service 2": {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "application_id:2 AND location_id:1"
          }
        }
      }
    }, [...]
  }
}
```

**But how can I get my top 5 services, by number of documents?** I guess I'll need `"size": 5` and `"order": { "<metric>": "desc"}`, however I don't exactly know how to articulate everything (for example, I don't know what  to put there, or how I can successfully sub-nest a sorting mechanism through a terms aggregation).

Comment: [By default, the buckets are ordered by their doc_count descending](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order)

Answer (score -1):

You can get top 5 services by size and order doc _count:

```
"aggs" : {
    "top_5_service" : {
        "terms" : {
            "field" : "service_id",
            "size" : 5,
            "order" : {
                "_count" : "desc"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `service_id` field doesn't exist, as stated in my question.